# Google Sheets - Sum row values in vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

I have G-Sheet like this one here:

[Sales Weekly](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E1141va9tINXbo4EC-FZzeSYY4e9R7SUnkaEF3kT6Gs/edit?usp=sharing)

In Sheet2 column I, I want to get sum qty from value in sheet Price

I have a formula like this:

```
TOTAL AVERAGE = Total Qty (week) * Grand Total
```

Then the expected sum qty from Price sheet is calculated with Grand Total

First, I've tried:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(A3, Price!C2:F, 4, False))*H3
```

Second, I've tried:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A3, Price!F3:H, 3, False))*H3
```

All formulas don't get a value that I expect.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A; QUERY({Price!D2:F}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1"); 2; 0)*H3:H))
```

[image]